# Look up method with own implementation instead of spring's proxy class

Tags: java, spring, proxy

When a singleton bean has reference of prototype bean, we use look up method in spring to inject new instance every time. As per Spring documentation, spring will create a proxy by generating sub class dynamically and override the lookup method. But I want my lookup method implementation to be used for creating instance of prototype bean instead of proxy sub class. Is there any way to do this?

Also as a curiosity, why Spring use proxy for look up method? Why cant they simply use implementation given by developer?